# What is the "Top 100 contributor" title?

Tags: magento-community, magento-connect

You can see a title "top 100 contributor" or "top 250 contributor" around the module reviews.

What does it mean?

I suppose the "top 100 contributor" is about the commenter and it means the commenter is in the top 100 of Magento Connect contributors. Or Magento community edition contributor or the contributor of an exact module? Where can I find a list about contributors? Where is the rules of this contributing?

example: http://reviews.magentocommerce.com/4643-en_us/4940/semantium-msemantic-semantic-seo-for-rich-snippets-in-google-and-yahoo-reviews/reviews.htm?page=5

Comment: Really interesting question.  I can find absolutely nothing about it in a Google search for it.  Perhaps this is @benmarks territory.

Comment: My guess (based on other "forum" like systems) it means someone does a lot of reviews/ratings. Like Yelp http://officialblog.yelp.com/2014/01/yelps-year-in-reviews.html Nothing to do with Magento itself. Reviews are handled by 3rd party system.

Answer (score 4):

There is some crystal-ball gazing involved in my answer, but I guess this is part of the "Bazaarvoice merit badges".

I already had typed up an answer citing the most important parts of a PDF document I found on bazaarvoice.com (thanks Google!), but then I noticed that there is a disclaimer disallowing to share this confidential information.

Without giving away specifics, there is a formula a score. The formula considers reviews with and without text, if the answers/reviews have been approved etc. with different weights. If your merit score is high enough and your review site has enough reviewers, you get badge X. I should notice the document is from 2012 so it may be outdated.

**Conclusion**: you get badges when you write a lot of reviews which also contain text, get approved and are regarded as helpful by other users.